# OO - resource spending and design confusion?

Tags: oop

sometimes i'm using OO des. and sometimes procedural style and everytime i use oop i feel like wasting resources on nothing. say i have a situation where i need to grab some values from datasource, a pool of bannerinfo. For the further work i can declare a banner class and decorators for additional functionality, but why would i do such a hard sequence - i got to grab, instantiate objects, fill them, wrap and so on, rather then just: grab data, run procedural code on data; yeah in many times oop just helps to organize logic and make decisions flexible, but on the other hand it's a waste of time on design (i experience a lot of problems solving simple stuff while putting them into oop style) and obviously a waste of machine resources. i'm kinda stuck in that mindset, im young but i've already seen some projects in oop - i wouldn't say that they're easy-understandable; that idead of oop is pretty charming - organising, making logically, but...
So, would you mind to point out some difference between situations when i should use oop/procedural styles. I'll appriciate any links to additional literature on that topic.Thanks!.

Comment: Depending on proyect complexity and size, OO is better than procedural style. Both are good, but each one have their space and application. Regards

Comment: i've heard so much of that mist. could u give some links on actual research. probably, an understanding'll come with age and experience, but i'm getting frustrated and exhausted of thinking whether i should go oop/procedural.

Comment: "This just sucks, am I right?" Please re-read the [faq] on on-topic constructive questions for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data you're grabbing has a structure to it, i.e. the order in which the fields show up within each record in the data source. The code you want to run on that data is closely bound to that structure (i.e. the code is not going to apply to other data structures, and if the data structure changes you certainly want to change the code). So it makes sense to keep the data and behaviour together from a "mental information management" point of view, and object are a great way to do this.

What if your program grows, and you want to iterate through bannerinfo in multiple places within the project? Of course you could create a routine available from the whole program which does what you want on the bannerinfo, and call that from each point where you need it. But what if you then think of other things you want to do with a bannerinfo? Of course you could just create another routine available from the whole program, but it would be completely separate from the first. What if these two routines had some code in common that you could push out to a separate routine, would you create yet another routine available from the whole program, even though it's only used by the other two?

With OOP you'd have a class with two public methods, and one private one for that third routine. Why is this different to having three routines available to the whole program? The answer is clutter. You can create as many additional methods on that class, and it won't add clutter to the parts where you're not using that particular class as they won't be available. If the data structure of bannerinfo changes, you only need to go to one place to make the changes.

Of course there's more, but I hope this helps demonstrate where OOP can be useful. Its all about making it easy to manage. If your specifc problem doesn't care for that because it is a one-off, or will never grow, then there's not necessarily any benefit.

Final note: whether the benefit is worth the effort also depends on other factors such as how comfortable you are with using objects, what you're trying to do with them (inheritance can get murky), and also on the language and syntax itself.

Answer (score 0):

"grab data, run procedural code on data"

I don't see how dealing with data can be easier with procedural. With OOP you can do stuff like

```
$users = $db->from('users')->where('score',100,'>')->getMany();
```

Or with an ORM:

```
$user = $orm->entity('User')->findOne($id);
$user->setPassword('abc123'); // set a new password
$orm->save($user);
```

About showing the data (also called 'the view' in MVC architecture), I have to agree that decorators can be annoying. But if you use a templating engine, things are easy as they can get. You didn't mention which language you are using, but if you are into PHP you can use [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Personally, I feel more comfortable with OOP even in small projects, where you don't even do things like unit-testing. But I think the best of OOP comes when you need maintainability, collaboration, reusability, etc.